# How to pass one model to another Rails Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, model-associations

I've been researching this a while and I'm still unclear on how to perform my intended action.  I feel like I may be using incorrect terminology, so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I have an application that has `documents` and `templates`, each their separate model.  I've got my models so that:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :template
end
```

and

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :document
end
```

and finally,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :templates
      has_many :documents, :through => :templates
end
```

My `user`/`documents` association seems to be working just fine.

I'd like to set up a workflow where a user would upload several templates, then select a `template` on the form for `/documents/new` to create a customized `document` based upon that template.  I have template_id as a field in my document model and intended to use some syntax on the order of `@document.template_id = template.id` on the new action in the `documents` controller.  I hit my first roadblock when I tried to use a `f.select` in the new view of my `documents` model, since I was unable to figure out a way to dynamically select from a list the current user's available templates.

I know I went a little long here, but hopefully someone can provide a helpful answer and/or some other SO posts or further reading beyond the standard [Rails Association Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/association_basics.html) that don't seem to address my needs.

Comment: It does seem that I can call `current_user.templates` from `documents/new` but the output doesn't make any sense (at least to me): `#<Template::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fb9dfa6e8e8>`

Comment: Can you print the output of `current_user.templates.first`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get an array of template names and their id's in your controller.

**For example:**

*Rails 4 and above*

```
@available_templates = @user.templates.pluck(:id, :name)
```

*Rails 3*

```
@available_templates = @user.templates.map{|tmplt| [tmplt.name, tmplt.id]}
```

And then in you `document/new` form do the following

```
=f.select :template_id, @available_templates,
 {prompt: 'Select a template'}, {required: true}
```

And you `document` model should be `belongs_to :template` instead of `has_many` since you have the `template_id` in your document instance.

Comment: I added `@template = Template.all` to my index view and was able to get an output off all the templates (all created by the same user), however when I added the `@available_templates = @user.templates.pluck(:id, :name)` (rails 4) to the list I got no output.  Do you think I should use `current_user` instead (using devise syntax)

Comment: Disregard, I had user.rb set with `has_many :templates, :through => :documents`, eliminated the `:through => documents` and was able to get a correct output on my index.  Still not getting the pluck function to work, will research it though - thanks for your insight

Comment: Yes `@user` is just for demonstration since I do not know exactly your variable name. it should be `current_user.templates.pluck(:id, :whetever)` And if this answers your question please mark it as the right answer! :)

Comment: your answer worked well for me, thank you.  I was not able to use the syntax provided for rails 4 for some reason, as it seems it was not selecting the correct template.  I reverted to the rails 3 syntax and it is working fine (even thought I'm using rails 4)